# in App Purchases iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I made my first app with IAP by 
[this tutorial](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

I made a singleton for InAppPurchaseManager, added 3 more purchases, methods for them and all works great. The problem is what my app is a gallery where user have 9 items free and after them 18 items paid. How can I check in my `ViewController` if purchase successfully made exactly when system `UIAletrView` is showing? Or maybe I can retrieve this alert in my `ViewController`?

For gallery I'm using `UICollectionView`, if purchase done I need reload it

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of the transaction by using this delegate method..

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        NSLog(@"%i",[transaction transactionState]);
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                // [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                // [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                // [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: {
                // if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(inProcessPurchasingTransaction)])
                // [self.delegate inProcessPurchasingTransaction];
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And the following delegate method will fire when the transaction success :

```
 - (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
```

And in case of fail :

```
- (void) failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
```

And for a testing purpose you need to create test user accounts. After you program the app, you might want to test the app. You can use these accounts to login to the App Store. The purchases will be processed as if it were real but no financial transactions will take place.